# Probability that i draws will be required to draw a white ball from a container of N balls without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

You are told you have a container containing N balls. There is only 1 white ball in the container.

S = The number of draws needed to obtain a white ball for the first time.

Prove that P(S = i) = 1/N if 1 <= i <= N

I do not understand how the probability of drawing a white ball can be 1/N on such a large range for i. I thought that the probability of drawing a white ball increases on every draw (i.e. P(S = 10) > P(S = 5)).

I am not understanding how such a scenario can lead to a constant probability which is independent of the value of i as long as i is between 1 and N.

My logic was as follows:

$$
P(S = i) = \prod_{n = 1}^{i} \frac{1}{N-n+1}
$$

But this is different than P(S = i) = 1/N

Did my professor perhaps write the wrong expression for the proof? Or is my logic wrong?

Edit:
My determined formula was obviously incorrect as I didn't factor in the fact that to draw a white ball on the i-th draw, the ball that was drawn beforehand must have been a black ball.

I adjusted the formula to reflect this:

$$
P(S = i) =\frac{1}{N-i+1} * \prod_{n=1}^{i-1} \frac{N-n}{N-n+1}
$$

This updated formula holds for any value of i such that 1 < i $\leq$ N and always returns 1/N. It makes sense when you consider the following scenarios:

P(S = 1) = 1/N

P(S = 2) = (N-1/N)(1/N-1)

P(S = 3) = (N-1/N)(N-2/N-1)(1/N-2)

P(S = 4) = (N-1/N)(N-2/N-1)(N-3/N-2)(1/N-3)

I haven't gotten to the induction part of the proof yet but that should complete this.

Comment: Is the question about *expected number* of draws or *probability* of getting a white ball on first draw ? Have you reproduced the *exact* wording of the question ?

Comment: As it is, your header and body conflict.

Comment: The balls are equally likely to be drawn in any order; in particular the white one is equally likely to be anywhere on the list.

Comment: @trueblueanil you are right, I was a little ambiguous. The exact meaning of my problem would be “what is the probability that the number of draws required to obtain the white ball will be i?”

Comment: Check your formula when $N=3$.  Do the probabilities sum to $1$?

Comment: @Lulu the probabilities do sum to 1 when N = 3 (1/3 + 1/6 + 1/6) but I understand what you're saying about how the white ball is equally likely to be anywhere on the list. The white ball can be any position so it's incorrect to say that it is more likely that the ball will be drawn after 5 draws as opposed to after 1. Looking at my formula a second time, and I see that it isn't even accurate as it regardless of the framework since it multiples fractions which only have a numerator of 1.

May I ask why you deleted your original answer? I felt it had answered the query rather eloquently.

Comment: $\frac 13+\frac 16+\frac 16$ is not $1$.  I deleted my posted solution because I decided this question must be a duplicate.  When I have time, I'll find a relevant post.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry my brain is muddled today. I adjusted the formula to adjust for the fact that a black ball will need to be chosen before the white ball is chosen and it now adds up. I haven't gotten to the induction yet but I appreciate your help a lot. I hadn't realized that the white ball is equally likely to be at any position in the set. This information jumpstarted my brain and helped me better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This represents a common misunderstanding.  Of course, the conditional probability increases as you draw successive non-white balls.  But you aren't asked for the conditional probability...just the a priori probability that a given ball is chosen in the $i^{th}$ draw, and that is indeed independent of $i$.

If it helps, work by induction. Clearly true if $n=1$ or $n=2$.  Suppose we have shown it for $n-1$ and suppose we have an urn with $n$ balls.  If $i=1$, then of course there is a $\frac 1n$ chance that we draw the white one first.  Each ball is equally likely to be drawn first, after all.  If $i>1$ then we need to get a non-white ball first after which we are down to $n-1$ balls and can use the inductive hypothesis.  Thus $$P(X=i)=\frac {n-1}n\times \frac 1{n-1}=\frac 1n$$

as desired.

For intuition, though, I think it's best to be simpler:  random drawing means that each of the $n!$ possible orders for the balls is equally probable.  And the white one is in the $i^{th}$ slot in exactly $(n-1)!$ of these.